# Why updating a nested array in an object doesn't trigger child component re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, dom

In my React app I have a page which consists of a list of item cards (each a separated component) and on each of those cards I have a table rendered from item's nested array objects. When I add an element to the nested array in item by creating a new item with updated array and setting the new list of items as state it does not trigger rerender of the table in the child component.
Here is the rough example of the code I have:

**Parent component**

```js
const Items = () => {
  // Fetching items in useEffect via API call
  const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useState([]);
  
  // This method is called in this component to add row to an item,
  // but I did not include this part to keep the example concise.
  const addRowToItem = (row, itemId) => {
    setItemsList(itemsList.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === itemId) {
        return {...item, rows: item.rows.concat(row)};
      }
      return item;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {itemsList.map((item) => (
        <ItemCard item={item} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child component (ItemCard)**

```js
const ItemCard = (props) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(props.item);

  return (
    <div>
      {item.rows.map((row) => (
        // Table row  
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Child component (ItemCard):
no need to define `useState` again. you can use the prop directly. remove the second line and:

```
{props.item.rows.map((row) => (
    // Table row  
  )}
```

I created a sandbox for, you check it out:
https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-breeze-ykzfln?file=/src/App.js

Comment: +1, the `useState` in the child takes only the initial `item` and won't update when prop updates. You can update it in the effect as well, but the best way is what @Reza mentioned - use it directly from props

Answer (score -1):

You could either use `useReducer` instead of `useState`, or clone the state object using the spread operator when assigning the value, like this:

```
const addRowToItem = (row, itemId) => {
    setItemsList([...itemsList.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === itemId) {
        return {...item, rows: item.rows.concat(row)};
      }
      return item;
    }])
  }
```

Comment: The `[... ]` here isn't really necessary as `.map()` already creates a new array, so there is no need to clone it. The issue is to do with the fact OP is creates state from their props in the child component, which won't update after the state has been set initially.